# How to copy and execute a file on remote machine?

Tags: python, remote-access, psexec

I tried this module, https://pypi.org/project/pypsexec/

But, it launches only executables or windows commands but not able to implement this.

But not able to implement any so far.
Tried pypsexec but it has only options to launch remote executables but not this level of filtering.

Have that option in direct psexec but not here.

Comment: How are you accessing the remote machine? What operating system is running on the remote machine?

Comment: both are windows. Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I would use scp to copy the file, then ssh to execute it. You could use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to execute the commands, or [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) if you want to do stuff interactively (e.g. use scp/ssh with passwords).

Comment: both are windows. Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

For copy part, you can use smbclient module in python to do the same.
If the required firewall exceptions are enabled.

Check this [link](https://pythonsiteblog.wordpress.com/2021/09/23/to-copy-files-to-remote-machine-using-python/) where I added the sample code for the same.